Linear recursion
I am new to recursion in general and not acquainted with much knowledge on linear algebra. question here
Our teacher had given us an assignment in functions, which had this question:
Now, It can be concluded that $T_n=4T_{n-1} + 9$. ($T_n$ is coefficient of $x^2$ in the denominator). I wanted to find the general term but brute force was the only thing I could think of. I tried finding patterns, by subtracting terms but to no avail. So I googled this. I had heard about the term recursion before but did not know much (it was introduced in our combinatorics course and discussed very briefly.
I am clueless as to how to proceed with this topic (general term as well of summation of a recursive series). I saw some answers on a general relation and characteristic equation (I have done matrices and determinants but I am not sure of the context here) but it went over my head.
Would be great if someone could give an approach to such problems, and how to dive into this topic and finally answer this question.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot

Using generating functions is my favorite way to handle linear recurrences. Any standard discrete mathematics text (like Rosen) will have a section on this.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g.,https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

@SeanRoberson How would u suggest going about this one.. and could u please post an answer? it becomes an easy reference

You can check about linear recurrence / recursion relations here: https://brilliant.org/wiki/linear-recurrence-relations/

Another typical approach to linear recurrences is to consider appropriate differences of terms, e.g., let $S_n:=T_{n+1}-T_n$. Then the recurrence implies $$S_{n}=T_{n+1}-T_n=(4T_n+9)-(4T_{n-1}+9)=4S_{n-1}$$ This eliminates the $+4$ offset.

@NagaSaiPrajith Thanks will do

@Semiclassical.. Oh that makes it very easy. The constant was problematic. Thanks a ton. However Even after we reduce it from S10 in terms of say S1 and manually find S1, How would we find T 10 then, because the requirement of T9 hasn't been eliminated?

@Semiclassical Help would be appreciated
